# Fluid images, div slightly out

Tags: html, css

Just practicing with fluid images.In the following code, I managed to get the image scale up/down with the browser window. The image is inserted inside the `.bigcontainer` div. `max-width` is used to achieve the scaling of the image along with windows. I have kept the background color of the `.bigcontainer` div as grey (just for identification purposes).

If you notice, the `.bigcontainer` div flows out slightly at the bottom of the image. This results in the grey color flowing out slightly at the bottom of the image. I want the div to fit (wrap) around the image perfectly. I don't know why is this happening.

Would appreciate inputs.

```css
html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 /* [disabled]width: 100%; */
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.wrapper {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 height: 100%;
 max-width: 960px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 margin-right: auto;
}


.bigcontainer {
 display: block;
 /* [disabled]border: 1px solid black; */
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 8.33%;
 margin-left: 8.33%;
 background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
 max-width: 100%;
 font-size: xx-large;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 top: 0px;
 height: auto;
}

.bigcontainer img{
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
}


.text {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="bigcontainer">
<img src="http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t482/gautam_official/royal-enfield-motorcycle-2x_zpswmyloqvc.jpg" alt="enfield">
</div>
<div class="text">
This is text. Its in center
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the link. Could you also help telling that how is it possible to put the text on top of this image?

Comment: Please do not ask single question [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709200/fluid-images-div-getting-repositioned)