# Fluid images, div getting repositioned

Tags: html, css

I am practicing with fluid images and divs layouts. In the following code, I managed to have a successful fluid image and fluid div's. However, one of the div on the left `.leftcolumn` (blue colored one) seems to flow vertically below a little into the bottom red div, whenever the browser window is re-sized to the smallest size. Please see the attached screenshot to understand the situation.

I know that this problem can be solved with media queries.But in this case, I am looking to understand as to WHY is this happening, and any alternative solution to this.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FtQb.jpg)

```css
html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 /* [disabled]width: 100%; */
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-size: medium;
}

.wrapper {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 960px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}


.bigcontainer {
 display: block;
 /* [disabled]border: 1px solid black; */
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 10%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
 max-width: 100%;
 font-size: xx-large;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 top: 0px;
 height: auto;
 /* [disabled]margin-bottom: -3px; */
 position: relative;
}

img{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 /* [disabled]margin-bottom: -9px; */
 display: block; 
}

.leftcolumn {
 width: 10%;
 height: 96%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.rightcolumn {
 width: 10%;
 background-color: rgba(204,255,0,1);
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}

.text {
 height: auto;
    width: auto;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0px;
}

.text2 {
 height: 10%;
 width: auto;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0%;
 font-size: 18px;
 /* [disabled]float: left; */
 margin-right: 10%;
}

.text3 {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 top: 0px;
 margin-left: 5%;
 font-size: 18px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftcolumn"></div>
  <div class="rightcolumn"></div>
  <div class="bigcontainer">
    <img src="http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t482/gautam_official/royal-enfield-motorcycle-2x_zpswmyloqvc.jpg" alt="enfield">
    <div class="text">This is text. Its in center</div>
  </div>
  <div class="text2">This one is below text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is exactly desired?

Comment: I don't want the blue div to flow into the red div below (as seen in the screenshot) whenever the browser window is scaled down.

Comment: yes, but thats giving a bit of different output in full screen browser window. I am looking to rectify just the expanding and contraction of left/right verticle columns whenever the browser window is scaled down/up. please see my updated code snippet above

Comment: yes, but thats giving a bit of different output in full screen browser window. I am looking to rectify just the expanding and contraction of left/right verticle columns whenever the browser window is scaled down/up. please see my updated code snippet above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Set `position:relative` to `.text2`.

This is happening because your element `.text2` is not set with `position:relative`. He is by default `position:static`, which means he is not "positioned" (anything but static is considered positioned). When an element is static it have no z-index and stay under the other "positioned" elements. Look at what [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com) say about setting the position to relative:

> "... One is that it introduces the ability to use z-index on that element, which doesn't really work with statically positioned elements. Even if you don't set a z-index value, this element will now appear on top of any other statically positioned element. You can't fight it by setting a higher z-index value on a statically positioned element."

In your case the other "positioned" elements are getting above your static `.text2`.

> "Elements with non-static positioning will always appear on top of elements with default static positioning."

[HERE](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) for more information about positioning and [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) to understand about z-index.

Sorry about my english.   :)

---

Based on the comments of this answer I'll try to elaborate another solution.

The thing is that the `.leftcolumn` have `height: 96%`. The 96% is the percentage related to the containing block (the `.wrapper`) that have no height set.

So another solution would be to put the `.leftcolumn` inside the `.bigcontainer`. The `.bigcontainer` would accomodate the `.leftcolumn` and the image. The height of the `.leftcolumn` would be set to 100%, now measuring the `.bigcontainer` as the containing box (that will have the image height). See the snippet:

```css
.wrapper {
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 960px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 position: relative;
}


.bigcontainer {
 display: block;
 background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 position: relative;
 max-width: 90%;
 height: 90%;
}

img{
 max-width: 90%;
 max-height:100%;
 margin-left:10%;
 display: block;
}

.leftcolumn {
 width: 10%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
}

.rightcolumn {
 width: 10%;
 background-color: rgba(204,255,0,1);
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}

.text {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 margin-left: 12%;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.text2 {
 height: 10%;
 width: auto;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0%;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-right: 10%;
}

.text3 {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 top: 0px;
 margin-left: 5%;
 font-size: 18px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <title>Teste</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
    <body>
 
  <div class="wrapper">
   
   <div class="rightcolumn"></div>
   <div class="bigcontainer">
    <div class="leftcolumn"></div>
    <img src="http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t482/gautam_official/royal-enfield-motorcycle-2x_zpswmyloqvc.jpg" alt="enfield">

    <div class="text">
     This is text. Its in center
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="text2">
   This one is below text
  </div>

  </div>
   
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It certainly does the work of stopping the blue div to overflow down on the red div whenever the browser window is scaled down to minimum. But it doesnt stop the blue div from going down, it now goes down on the back on red div (I have updated the code and removed the color of the red div so that you can notice). Why is this happening and what can we do to avoid the blue div from expanding than its 100% set height whenever the browser window is scaled down to minimum?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Lastly, I was wondering if you can help me out with this: In the above code, I added `margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;` to `.text` because I wanted to horizontally align the above text (text on top of image - "This is text. Its in center" to the center. Usually we can do this by adding setting left/right margin to auto. But it's not happening. Can you explain why? I know there is a way out of this by increasing the `.text` width to 100%, the text will align itself to center, but that will not help me understand cause of the problem. I want the DIV to align to center

Comment: You have set `.wrapper { text-align: center; }`, this makes all the text of what is inside `.wrapper` to be aligned center relative to the width of its container. The `.text` have no width and, for this reason, cannot understand where to center anything. As soon as you set `width:100%` it now will have something to work with and can align horizontally.

Comment: `.text {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 0px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired output?

```css
.wrapper{
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper, .leftupper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.left{
  flex-basis: 90%;
  color: white;
}

.right{
  flex-basis: 10%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: rgba(204,255,0,1);
}

.left .leftupperleft{
  flex-basis: 10%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}

.left .leftupperright{
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
}

.left .leftupperright .text{
  position: absolute;
}

.left .leftupperright img{
  width: 100%;
}

.left .leftlower{
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="leftupper">
            <div class="leftupperleft">
            </div>
            <div class="leftupperright">
                <div class="text">This is text. Its in center</div>
                <img src="http://i1062.photobucket.com/albums/t482/gautam_official/royal-enfield-motorcycle-2x_zpswmyloqvc.jpg" alt="enfield">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="leftlower">This one is below text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```